# Select always first value select vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do I always select the first item with a select (in vue.js)?

```
<div class="ride-item-content">
  <select v-model="ride.location_id">
    <option v-for="location in locations" v-bind:value="location.id">
      {{ location.from }} - {{ location.to }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**json**

```
{
  "locations": {
    "total": 2,
    "per_page": 20,
    "current_page": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "next_page_url": null,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "from": 1,
    "to": 2,
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "description": "sdg",
        "from": "asdf",
        "to": "asdf",
        "kmz": "12",
        "kmp": "13",
        "time": 0,
        "hour": 0,
        "maps": "www.blablabla.nl",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "user_id": 1,
        "description": "asdf",
        "from": "asdf",
        "to": "asdf",
        "kmz": "3",
        "kmp": "1",
        "time": 1,
        "hour": 0,
        "maps": "www.test.nl",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

--EDIT--

```
<div class="ride-item-content">
  <select v-model="ride.location_id">
    <option v-for="location in locations" v-bind:selected="$index === 0 ? 'selected' : false">
      {{ location.from }} - {{ location.to }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

VueJS 1:

```
<option v-for="location in locations" v-bind:value="location.id" v-bind:selected="$index === 0 ? 'selected' : false">
  {{ location.from }} - {{ location.to }}
</option>
```

VueJS 2:

```
<option v-for="(location, index) in locations" v-bind:value="location.id" v-bind:selected="index === 0">
  {{ location.from }} - {{ location.to }}
</option>
```

In Vue 1, `$index` is automatically available inside `v-for` loops.

In Vue 2, you need to explicitly declare a variable for the index.

Comment: Thankyou, but it's not working? I use vueJS 1. Please see my edit.

Comment: The solution for vuejs 2 won't work if you are using `v-model` on the select. See first note in [this docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage)

Comment: :selected and :value are also correct in VueJS v2 :)

Comment: @Choma in that case how do you use v-modal on the select and also default to first on the index to be selected? Not sure from the referenced link. Thanks

Comment: @raison, I guess there may be several ways to do this, but [here is an easy one](https://jsfiddle.net/xk84ag52/)

Comment: @Choma thanks that's really helpful and can see how to do this now. I'm just stuck because I'm using Vuex and created() gives empty array. So I must find a way to trigger setting this after Vuex objects defined...

Answer (score 4):

In your json I cant find `location.id`. And your `"locations"` is obj. But if the `"locations"` is arr, you can use this:

```
  <select v-model="selectedLocation">
    <option v-for="location in locations" :key="location.id" :value=location.id>
      {{ location.somekey }}
    </option>
  </select>
```

in data -

```
selectedLocation: this.locations.length ? this.locations[0].id : ''
```

It can work because your select depends on selectedLocation `(v-model)`.

Comment: you solution doesn't work it give me Cannot read property ' ..... ' of undefined, seems that data work some differently

Answer (score 2):

```js
created(){
    if(this.locations) {
        this.ride.location_id = this.locations[0].id
    }
}
```

working example jsfidlle link
https://jsfiddle.net/Rashid_Bukhari/q2ro6pz1/20/

you just need to update your v-model `ride.location_id` into vuejs `created(){}` or `mounted(){}` method

Answer (score 1):

You can use v-model in your select , when you load your list pass first value to a model variable and always first value will be selected

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @J. Bruni's answer although that seemed to not work for you. Try this:

```
<option v-for="location in locations" v-bind:value="location.id" v-bind:selected="$index === 0 ? true : false">
    {{ location.from }} - {{ location.to }}
</option>
```