# How to select the first option in a select as default in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to make the first option be selected when populating a select in Vue 3. I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668363/select-always-first-value-select-vue-js) but none of the answers worked for me.

Here is my code

js:

```
const newOfferApp = createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            message: "Ok vue is working ... ",
            form: {
                modifications: [],
                makes: ["Abarth", "AC", "Acura", "Aixam"],
            },
            offer: {
                model: '',
                make: ''
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        fetchModification() {
            this.form.modifications =
                [
                    {key: "0", value: "MDX"},
                    {key: "1", value: "NSX"},
                    {key: "2", value: "RL"}
                ]

            this.offer.model = this.form.modifications[0];
        }
    }
});
```

html:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
   <label for="make" class="form-label">{{ __('new.make') }}</label>
   <select v-model="offer.make" @change="fetchModification"
      class="form-control"
      id="make"
      name="make">
      <option v-for="(make,i) in form.makes" :value="make" :selected="i === 0">
         @{{make}}
      </option>
   </select>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
   <label for="modification" class="form-label">{{ __('new.model') }}</label>
   <select v-model="offer.model"
      name="id"
      class="form-control"
      id="modification">
      <option v-for="(mod,index) in form.modifications " :key="mod.value" :value="mod.value"
         :selected="index === 0">
         @{{ mod.value }}
      </option>
   </select>
   <div class="invalid-feedback">
   </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE: I am using Laravel that is why you can see @{{}} instead of {{}}**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the values on `created` as follows:

```
created() {
  const { makes = [], modifications = [] } = this.form;
  this.offer = { 
    make:  makes[0], 
    model: modifications.length > 0 ? modifications[0].value : ''
  }; 
}
```

No need for the `:selected="index === 0"`

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for this. Sigh...  2 years too late.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the `:selected="index === 0"`, and in  `this.offer.model = this.form.modifications[0];` you're passing the entire obj; it shuld be  `this.offer.model = this.form.modifications[0].value;`