# How to I make the select drop down show the currently selected value in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Similar to [Select always first value select vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668363/select-always-first-value-select-vue-js) but I am making a custom component.

I have an SFC with a few extra debug output

```
<script>
export default {
  props: ['modelValue', 'options'],
  emits: ['update:modelValue']
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    
  <select
    :value="modelValue"
    @change="$emit('update:modelValue', JSON.parse($event.target.value))"
  >
    <option value="" disabled>no selection</option>
    <option v-for="option in options" :value="JSON.stringify(option)" :selected="JSON.stringify(modelValue) === JSON.stringify(option)">X{{JSON.stringify(option)}}X{{JSON.stringify(modelValue) === JSON.stringify(option)}}</option>
  </select>
     {{modelValue}}
  </div>
</template>
```

And a calling component

```
<script>
import CustomInput from './CustomInput.vue'

export default {
  components: { CustomInput },
  data() {
    return {
      message: '',
      blah: [
        {a:"a"},
        {b:2},
        {c:{d:1}},
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
        theMessage() {
      return JSON.stringify(this.message);
    }
}
}
</script>

<template>
  <CustomInput v-model="message" :options="blah"/> {{ theMessage }}
</template>
```

But I am not able to get the selected item to appear in the dropdown even if the "label" is showing it should be selected.

[Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Why does your `blah` object look like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use v-model in your child component and bubble the event to parent with computed setter/getter

App.vue

```
<script>
import CustomInput from './CustomInput.vue'

export default {
  components: { CustomInput },
  data() {
    return {
      message: '',
      blah: [
        {a:"a"},
        {b:2},
        {c:{d:1}},
      ]
    }
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <CustomInput v-model="message" :options="blah" /> {{ message }}
</template>
```

CustomInput.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  props: ['modelValue', 'options'],
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  computed: {
    internalValue: {
      get() {
        return this.modelValue;
      },
      set(newVal) {
        this.$emit('update:modelValue', newVal)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
  <select

        v-model="internalValue"
  >
    <option value="" disabled>no selection</option>
    <option v-for="option in options" :value="JSON.stringify(option)" :selected="JSON.stringify(modelValue) === JSON.stringify(option)">{{
      option}}</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</template>
```

(I'm not sure your JSON.stringy is usefull)

Comment: the value I want to be bubbled up was the object rather than the JSON string.